# Can function tail-recursive

Tags: function, scala, tail-recursion

I have some recursion code I want to refactor to use tail recursive from [Enumerator](http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2010/10/17/scalaz-tutorial-enumeration-based-io-with-iteratees/), I can simplify that recursion to look like this, please ignore what functionality this functionality wants to achieve.

```
@tailrec
def doStuff: List[Int] => Int = {
      case Nil => 0
      case x :: xs => doStuff(xs)
    }
```

If I get rid of tailrec annotation, it is working fine, the structure looks like this doStuff(doStuff(doStuff(..))). It will have stackoverflow exception.

So how can I make it tail recursive if it is a function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anonymous functions cannot be made tail-recursive. Let us first do a very simple rewrite of your code to introduce a `val` to hold the resulting function.

```
@tailrec
def doStuff: List[Int] => Int = {
  val result: List[Int] => Int = {
    case Nil => 0
    case x :: xs => doStuff(xs)
  }
  result
}
```

It should be clear, from there, that `doStuff(xs)` is *not* calling the anonymous function itself. It is calling the method `doStuff`, which *returns* the function you want to call. Worse, since it is a `def`, it actually returns a *different function on every call*. Hence the anonymous function is definitely not calling *itself*.

The problem generalizes to this simple fact: anonymous functions are, well, anonymous. So there's no way they can call themselves directly: they're always calling some other `def` or `val` that might return themselves, but the compiler doesn't know that.

For this reason, only proper `def`s like the one proposed by @dhg will truly be tail-recursive.

Now, if you really want to return a function value, that happens to be implemented with a tail-recursive case, you can simply convert a method into a function using `theMethod _`. Hence, the solution to your initial problem would be the following:

```
val doStuff = {
  @tailrec
  def rec(list: List[Int]): Int = list match {
    case Nil => 0
    case x :: xs => rec(xs)
  }
  rec _
}
```

Note that we declare a proper tail-recursive *method* (`rec`), that we then transform into a function value with `rec _`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you mean this?

```
@tailrec
def doStuff(list: List[Int]): Int = list match {
  case Nil => 0
  case x :: xs => doStuff(xs)
}
```

Comment: not really, the return type of this is Int, I still want to return type to be a function. If you look at the implementation of enumerateFile in this http://blog.higher-order.com/blog/2010/10/14/scalaz-tutorial-enumeration-based-io-with-iteratees/ . almost all the recursive function are not tail recursive. That is something I want to change.

Comment: @Cloudtech [you can turn it to function value with `doStuff _` call](http://scalafiddle.net/console/7bd66825e9a97424ffe5645549270832)

Answer (score 0):

> So how can I make it tail recursive if it is a function

You can't. I mean, of course you can write a tail-recursive function in Scala, but it won't help you because it won't get optimized.

Scala only optimizes direct tail-recursive method calls.